# Android: How can I achieve a divider with a textview in the center?

Tags: android

I can create a divider using this code:

```
<View
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="1dp"
   android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
   android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
```

But how can I add a text view in the center of the divider like this one: [image]

Comment: try settext(""----text----");

Comment: I don't have that option on a View

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this:

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Some text" />


        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    </LinearLayout>
```